# how to evaluate an dynamically generated if elif else statement in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, eval

im having trouble getting a dynamically generated shell function to evaluate properly (by evaluate i mean "eval" command)

this is the desired statement to be evaluated when ran (except the output will be executed/evaluated by eval)

```
$ package_check_repo_printf
if [ $(printf '%s\n' "found ${treelistnew0[@]}" | grep -i -e ^"$1") ]
    then
    url=$POOL0$1
    ftp=$ftpPOOL0$1
    echo $1 found in $POOL0
elif [ $(printf '%s\n' "found ${treelistnew1[@]}" | grep -i -e ^"$1") ]
    then
    url=$POOL1$1
    ftp=$ftpPOOL1$1
    echo $1 found in $POOL1
else
    echo $1 not found
fi
```

and its code:

```
package_check_repo_printf() {
for i in ${!REPOS[@]}
    do
if [[ $ifgen == "" ]]
then
printf '%s' "if [ \$(printf '%s\n' \"found \${treelistnew0[@]}\" | grep -i -e ^\"\$1\") ]
    then
    url=\$POOL0\$1
    ftp=\$ftpPOOL0\$1
    echo \$1 found in \$POOL0
"
ifgen=gen
else
printf '%s' "elif [ \$(printf '%s\n' \"found \${treelistnew$i[@]}\" | grep -i -e ^\"\$1\") ]
    then
    url=\$POOL$i\$1
    ftp=\$ftpPOOL$i\$1
    echo \$1 found in \$POOL$i
"
fi
done
printf '%s' "else
    echo \$1 not found
fi"
}
```

when i replace all the printf '%s' with eval i get this

```
package_check_repo_eval() {
set -v
for i in ${!REPOS[@]}
    do
if [[ $ifgen == "" ]]
then
eval "if [ \$(printf '%s\n' \"found \${treelistnew0[@]}\" | grep -i -e ^\"\$1\") ]
    then
    url=\$POOL0\$1
    ftp=\$ftpPOOL0\$1
    echo \$1 found in \$POOL0
"
ifgen=gen
else
eval "elif [ \$(printf '%s\n' \"found \${treelistnew$i[@]}\" | grep -i -e ^\"\$1\") ]
    then
    url=\$POOL$i\$1
    ftp=\$ftpPOOL$i\$1
    echo \$1 found in \$POOL$i
"
fi
done
eval "else
    echo \$1 not found
fi"
set +v
}
```

and its output ( note for this to be CORRECT it should look the same as the package_check_repo_printf's output as set -v will echo the lines executed as printf is not printing the lines) :

```
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ unset ifgen
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ package_check_repo_eval
if [ $(printf '%s\n' "found ${treelistnew0[@]}" | grep -i -e ^"$1") ]
    then
    url=$POOL0$1
    ftp=$ftpPOOL0$1
    echo $1 found in $POOL0
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
elif [ $(printf '%s\n' "found ${treelistnew1[@]}" | grep -i -e ^"$1") ]
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
else
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$
```

how would i get this to work correctly?

note: just to be clear, my goal is to make this function EVAL based instead of PRINTF based

a better example would be this (although im not sure if this is acomplishable another way but still, it generates a usable if elif else statement)

```
dogs=(1 2 3)
dog=(pink blue white)
colour=(pink black white)
dogs_printf() {
unset ifgen
for i in ${!dogs[@]}
    do
if [[ $ifgen == "" ]]
then
printf '%s' "for i in \${!dogs[@]}
do
if [[ \${dog[i]} == \"\${colour[$i]}\" ]]
    then
    echo dog$i is \"\${colour[$i]}\"
"
ifgen=gen
else
printf '%s' "elif [[ \${dog[i]} == \"\${colour[$i]}\" ]]
    then
    echo dog$i is \"\${colour[$i]}\"
"
fi
done
printf '%s' "else
    echo dog \$i not found
fi
done
"
}
dogs_printf
```

its output:

```
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ dogs=(1 2 3)
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ dog=(pink blue white)
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ colour=(pink black white)
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ dogs_printf() {
> unset ifgen
> for i in ${!dogs[@]}
>     do
> if [[ $ifgen == "" ]]
> then
> printf '%s' "for i in \${!dogs[@]}
> do
> if [[ \${dog[i]} == \"\${colour[$i]}\" ]]
>     then
>     echo dog$i is \"\${colour[$i]}\"
> "
> ifgen=gen
> else
> printf '%s' "elif [[ \${dog[i]} == \"\${colour[$i]}\" ]]
>     then
>     echo dog$i is \"\${colour[$i]}\"
> "
> fi
> done
> printf '%s' "else
>     echo dog \$i not found
> fi
> done
> "
> }
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ dogs_printf
for i in ${!dogs[@]}
do
if [[ ${dog[i]} == "${colour[0]}" ]]
    then
    echo dog0 is "${colour[0]}"
elif [[ ${dog[i]} == "${colour[1]}" ]]
    then
    echo dog1 is "${colour[1]}"
elif [[ ${dog[i]} == "${colour[2]}" ]]
    then
    echo dog2 is "${colour[2]}"
else
    echo dog $i not found
fi
done
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$ for i in ${!dogs[@]}
> do
> if [[ ${dog[i]} == "${colour[0]}" ]]
>     then
>     echo dog0 is "${colour[0]}"
> elif [[ ${dog[i]} == "${colour[1]}" ]]
>     then
>     echo dog1 is "${colour[1]}"
> elif [[ ${dog[i]} == "${colour[2]}" ]]
>     then
>     echo dog2 is "${colour[2]}"
> else
>     echo dog $i not found
> fi
> done
dog0 is pink
dog 1 not found
dog2 is white
[chakra@chakra-pc UPM]$
```

Comment: You might want to simplify your example a little bit, i.e. try to come up with a minimal example that produces the same problem. Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but it looks like there's a lot of superfluous stuff here.

Comment: I really hope this is just a toy problem you created for fun, because otherwise what you're doing here is utterly horrifying.

Comment: reduced it to problem only, got rid of the examples even though they may provide help

Comment: and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74972/parthian-shot how would you improve the script since it is "utterly horrifying"

Comment: @ClarkKent What I meant was more along the lines of removing everything you possibly can while still producing the same error, e.g. remove all of the extraneous variables and function calls.

Comment: @ClarkKent Learn how to properly quote parameter expansions before you even *think* about trying to generate code that will be passed to `eval`.

Comment: This should be asked on Stack Overflow, with a strong emphasis on how to accomplish the ultimate task *without* using `eval`.

Comment: @ClarkKent Adding on to chepner's advice, I suspect that the specific problem you're having is related to quoting parameters, but I think it would be easier to give you useful feedback if you trimmed down your examples a lot more.

Comment: what im trying to do is execute the printf generated statement directly without needing to output it into a file then source that file

Comment: @ClarkKent Look at my updated solution. I included a second example that might be closer to what you're trying to get at.

Comment: @ClarkKent I just looked at your original example a little more carefully, and it looks like you're trying to evaluate fragments of the generated if-statement rather than the entire statement. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @igal how would i evaluate the entire statement?

Comment: @ClarkKent You could generate the entire statement and then pass that to `eval` as a single argument. Look at my solution - that's what I do. I'd also like to add that I agree with the other users who have suggested that this is probably not the best way to accomplish your ultimate goal.

Comment: @igal yay it works

Comment: @ClarkKent Great! In that case you might want to upvote & accept my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but here is a very simple example that addresses the question in the title (how to evaluate a dynamically generated if-statement in the shell):

```
#!/bin/bash

# eval_dynamic_if_then

# Get a command to test from the user
COMMAND="$*"

# Construct an if-then statement using the user
# supplied command and save it to a variable
read -r -d '' IF_THEN <<HEREDOC
if eval "${COMMAND}"; then
  echo "Command successful!"
else
  echo "Command NOT successful!"
fi
HEREDOC

# Evaluate the command
eval "${IF_THEN}"
```

Here is an example invocation of this script:

```
./eval_dynamic_if_then true
```

This results in the following output:

```
Command successful!
```

Alternatively:

```
./dynamic_if_then false
```

produces:

```
Command NOT successful!
```

Since you're also experimenting with `printf`, here is an adaption which only prints the command instead of evaluating it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# print_dynamic_if_then

# Get a command to test from the user
COMMAND="$*"

# Construct an if-then statement using the user
# supplied command and save it to a variable
read -r -d '' IF_THEN <<HEREDOC
if eval "${COMMAND}"; then
  echo "Command successful!"
else
  echo "Command NOT successful!"
fi
HEREDOC

# Print the command
printf "${IF_THEN}"
```

Now to evaluate the output of this script you would do something like the following:

```
eval "$(print_dynamic_if_then true)"
```

Notice that the substitution is quoted, e.g. the following won't work:

```
eval $(print_dynamic_if_then true)
```

This results in the following error message:

```
-bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Looking at your original example, it looks like you wanted to replace `printf` statements with `eval` statements in places where the argument string being passed in was only a code-fragment and not a complete shell statement. The solution to that particular problem is to generate the entire statement to be executed before passing it to the `eval` command.

I'd also like to echo the comments of other users who recommended against this approach. If I were you I would consider thinking about a way to accomplish your ultimate goal without relying on the `eval` command.

Comment: made my question a bit more clear (hopefully) if not then tell me what you do not understand

Comment: Can you remove everything having to do with checking repositories and replace it with some simple boiler plate?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a comparison to the `printf` approach you seem to be using in the body of your post.

Comment: i tried that but i got the same result as you even if i quoted the printf function

Comment: i made a more usable example

Comment: @ClarkKent I'm sorry, but I still don't understand exactly what the problem is. The last example you added seems to work.